# Incluir extremos no BETWEEN e Listar valores faltantes na consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Seguinte. Imagine que eu tenha no banco no campo de meses pagos os seguintes lançamentos: 2015-03, 2015-04, 2015-7, 2015-9. 
Se estipulassemos um período por exemplo: de 2015-02 até hoje (2015-9). Quais são os meses que faltam, ou seja, quais meses ainda não foram pagos.

A query que apresento aqui traz os meses pagos ***DENTRO*** do período. 
Mas o que eu preciso ***NÃO SÃO*** os meses pagos, mas ***SIM*** os ***MESES NÃO PAGOS*** e ***DENTRO*** do período. Ou seja, 2015-2, 2015-5, 2015-6, 2015-8.

```
 SELECT pagamentos.idPagamentos, pagamentos.mesReferencia FROM pagamentos, planosclientes
 WHERE
        pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = planosclientes.idPlanosClientes AND
        pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = 8 AND
        pagamentos.mesReferencia BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(planosclientes.dataInstalacao, '%Y%-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y%-%m')
 ORDER BY pagamentos.mesReferencia
```

Como fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Carlos acho que não entendi direito o que precisa, você quer os extremos, não seria só usar os sinais de < e > em vez de between? porque creio eu que não tem extremo após o curdate() nessa dataInstalação, ou tem ?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para ficar mais fácil a interpretação!

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é usar `DATEADD`, tirando um mês da `dataInstalacao` e adicionando um mês na `CURRENT_DATE()`.

```
SELECT pagamentos.idPagamentos, pagamentos.mesReferencia 
FROM pagamentos, planosclientes
WHERE pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = planosclientes.idPlanosClientes 
   AND pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = 8 
   AND pagamentos.mesReferencia 
      BETWEEN FORMAT(DATEADD(mm,-1,planosclientes.dataInstalacao), 'yyyy-MM') 
      AND FORMAT(DATEADD(mm,1,CURRENT_DATE()), 'yyyy-MM') ;
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Função `DATE_FORMAT` e `DATE_ADD` (para MYSQL):

```
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(planosclientes.dataInstalacao, -1 INTEVAL MONTH), '%Y-%M') 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%M')
```

No entanto, `BETWEEN` inclui os limites, ou seja, não seria necessário fazer nenhum ajuste de data.

Porém percebi que você está fazendo between entre `varchar`o que não dará certo.

Sendo assim, você deve fazer o `CAST` para dates dos valores a serem comparados e para isso o código ficaria assim:

```
AND CAST(CONCAT(pagamentos.mesReferencia, '01') as DATE)
   BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(FORMAT(planosclientes.dataInstalacao), '%Y-%m'), '01') as DATE) 
   AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: Esse mm, -1 esta dano erro: ...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1,planosclientes.dataInstalacao), '%Y%-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(mm,1,CURRE' at line 5

Comment: No seu comentário o código está errado... Ajustei também a resposta.
`pagamentos.mesReferencia BETWEEN format(dateadd(mm,-1,dataInstalacao), 'yyyy-MM')
    AND format(dateadd(mm,1,GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM')`

Comment: Mensagem do MySQL: Documentação

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1,planosclientes.dataInstalacao), 'y-m') AND FORMAT(DATEA_DD(mm,1,CURRENT_DATE(' at line 5

Comment: atualizei a pergunta mostrando o erro que dá!

Comment: Carlos, cometi um engano... Agora que vi que você está usando MySQL. O código que coloquei na resposta é para SQL.
Em MySQL `BETWEEN` inclui os limites. Opcionalmente você pode usar os operadores `>=` e `<=`.
A função `DATE_ADD` do mysql usa a seguinte sintaxe (exemplo usando o seu código):
`DATE_ADD(planosclientes.dataInstalacao, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Answer (score 0):

Até onde entendi você quer < esses > <------Periodo------> < e esses> certo? vamos lá:

```
     SELECT pagamentos.idPagamentos, pagamentos.mesReferencia FROM pagamentos, planosclientes
 WHERE
        pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = planosclientes.idPlanosClientes AND
        pagamentos.idPlanoClientes = 8 AND
        pagamentos.mesReferencia < DATE_FORMAT(planosclientes.dataInstalacao, '%Y%-%m') AND 
        pagamentos.mesReferencia > DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y%-%m')
 ORDER BY pagamentos.mesReferencia;
```

Ou seja os menores < que ***dataInstalacao*** e os maiores > que o ***curdate()*** (dia atual) assim teremos os chamados "extremos"

Comment: Não! Seguinte.Imagine que eu tenha no banco no campo de ***meses pagos*** os seguintes lançamentos: 2015-03, 2015-04, 2015-7, 2015-9. Se estipularmos um período por exemplo: de 2015-02 até hoje (2015-9). Quais são os meses que faltam, ou seja, quais meses ***ainda não foram pagos***. A ***query*** que apresentei no final da pergunta traz os meses pagos ***DENTRO*** do período. O que eu preciso são dos meses ***NÃO*** pagos e ***DENTRO*** do período. Ou seja, 2015-2, 2015-5, 2015-6, 2015-8. Melhorou?

Comment: Entendi, segunda faço uns testes de SQL então